# Django PermissionRequiredMixin redirect to login template with message

Tags: django, django-templates, django-permissions

I got this view and I'm using `PermissionRequiredMixin` on it...it works fine but when I redirect to login template (set in settings `LOGIN_URL`) I need it shows a message there like **"You don't have permission to do this"**. Any idea how to do it without creating a custom decorator, just using `PermissionRequiredMixin` itself?

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin

class MyView(PermissionRequiredMixin,View):

    template = 'myapp/item_detail.html'
    permission_required = 'myapp.change_item'


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #Query here
        return render(request, self.template)
```

What do I need to add in order to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [the messaging framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/). To add your own message, simple overwrite:

```
from django.contrib import messages

class MyView(...):
    ...

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        # add custom message
        messages.error(self.request, 'You have no permission')
        return super(MyView, self).handle_no_permission()
```

you'll also need to add the following to your `base.html` (or login form):

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
        <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach:

1. Override `handle_no_permission(self)` in your view:

```py
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin

class MyView(PermissionRequiredMixin,View):
    
    template = 'myapp/item_detail.html'
    permission_required = 'myapp.change_item'

    def handle_no_permission(self):
        messages.error(self.request, 'You don't have permission to do this')
        return super(MyView, self).handle_no_permission()
```

2. Make sure [messages are visible](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages) in login template and `django.contrib.messages` added to `INSTALLED_APPS`.